# secured centralized logs collection through USB flash drives

Tags: usb-device, datalogger

I want to centralize logs collection from many different computers on which I can only plug USB flash drives. This is the only authorized device for some security reasons (even if a USB flash drive could still be infected :( ). Those computers should not be reachable from the network in any case to prevent any network attack.

A solution could be to design a device acting as a USB flash drive on one side linked to an Ethernet interface on the other side. Any log written on the USB flash drive would be pushed to the Ethernet module, the Ethernet module would automatically send any incoming data to a target IP. The link between the USB and Ethernet module would be simplex (hardware design) so that no attack on the Ethernet module could compromize the USB flash drive connected on each computer.

Should I design such a hardware or does it already exist and would only require specific programming ? Would you think of a better solution ?

Thanks a lot for your help

PS: unfortunately, not all of those computers have a serial interface (which could have been a good solution)

Comment: I have seen wifi-enabled SD cards, you could plug one of them into a USB-SD adaptor,

Comment: if the module does not prevent a wifi to SD card attack by design (hardware), I could not guarantee that it would be secured from a smart network attack ?

Comment: Secure sneakernet?

Comment: a kind of centralized real-time secure sneakernet

Comment: i can't see how they could allow writing, fat-32 is a single user filesystem, but this does not mean it's secure by design.

Comment: unfortunately the security guarantee is core in my problem

Comment: This discussion seems to address a problem similar to yours http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/serve-files-over-usb

Comment: @Vinod very interesting link. Now I need to sort out which of those different alternatives will bring hardware security guarantees

Answer (score 1):

a usb serial port would make more sense than a flash drive,  interpreting writes to a mounted filesystem in realtime is a tricky task,

serial to wifi or serial to ethernet is fairly easy, and if you don't connect the RX wire on the serial simplex is guaranteed.

Comment: you're right but some of those computers do not have a serial interface. In fact I don't need true real-time as even a 1 second delay would still be acceptable

Comment: usb-serial (CP2101, FT232 etc) is an option, but you may need the have the rules changed to allow that.

Comment: would the CP2101 be recognized as a USB flash drive ? I cannot add other USB devices than USB flash drive (USB storage)

Comment: no, it will show up as usb communication device.  the rules are stupid, find the original author and get them changed.

Comment: It's a matter of certification in my case

Comment: if certification cost is less than $2000 it's still probably cheaper than messing with dual-ported storage, especially long term.